# function running before javascript include via bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, So I am writing a bookmarklet which will hopefully eventully turn into a plugin that will check the current url and then redirect them to another page based on that URL. The problem I an running into is that one of my functions is running before the new js file is included. An example would be me loading jquery and sweet alert then running the sweet alert function:

```
function loadElements() {
    var addjquery = document.createElement('script');
    addjquery.src = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js';
    document.head.appendChild(addjquery);
    // Then add sweet alert js/css
}
function runstuff() {
    swal("Its good!!","yay","success");
}
```

Then I run the two back to back

```
loadElements();
runstuff();
```

Now what happens is when I run this bookmarklet is I get an error stating that `swal is not defined`. But when I run it a second time it works perfectly fine and as expected. Any ideas how I can delay the "runstuff" function from running until the javascript is loaded?

Comment: You need a callback when the script is loaded, it's asynchronous.

Comment: Why add jquery this way?

Comment: Javascript is the one language I kept putting off learning but now I actually need to use it. So Im all ears on a better way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a callback when the script is loaded, it's asynchronous:

```
addjquery.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
    alert('jQuery Loaded');
    console.log(e);
    runStuff();
}, false);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/3fwkr1c8/)**